# What are the best ways to balance the classes in multilabel classification?

Tags: class-imbalance, multilabel-classification

I have around 1000 rows of data with 9 labels. Each label can be either 1 or 0. Out of 9 labels I have 1 label which has 600 1s , 3 labels which have around 300 1s rest are having around 50 1s. I tried building classifier chains, however I see the precision and recall for minority classes are too low. What would be the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Why do you build classifier chains? In multilabel classification the labels are supposed to be predicted independently from each other.

Comment: Thank you. When are we supposed to use classifier chains? I thought classifier chains helped capture correlation between the labels.

Comment: Sorry I just saw that my comment was misguided: I didn't know about this kind of classifier chains for multi-label classification, you're right that the method seems appropriate. In general it's not recommended to change the distribution of the classes, and in this specific case of classifier chains I think that it would break the statistical dependency between labels. That's probably not the answer you're looking for, but it's often unavoidable that small classes get poor performance.